# Give fixed cell spacing between collectionView cells in swift 4

Tags: uitableview, collections, cell, spacing

I want to give fixed cell spacing between the collection view cells which scroll horizontally. Is there any option to give maximum cell spacing between cells?

Answer (score 0):

For setting space between rows

```
[self.collectionView setMinimumLineSpacing:10];
```

For setting space between items/cells.

```
[self.collectionView setMinimumInteritemSpacing:10];
```

Or you can (if you have) configure it directly from the Storyboard

[image: Storyboard]